# What's the point of the drone's second view mode?

Tags: ghost-recon-future-soldier

The drone has the option to change it vision type (Ⓧ on the PS3), but it just seem to make all the darker parts lighter, decreasing the contrast and making things harder to see. It doesn't seem to let me see through walls or improve visibility in the open or in dust/snow. What good is it?

Answer (score 1):

It's point is to make target's visibility clearer as each type of vision suites a specific climate, weather, time and angle of view. Remember the C-130 Support mission on Call of Duty 4 : Modern Warfare? You had the same two heat visions in that mission too, however it doesn't grant you to see through walls as that requires more sophisticated technology to be mounted on a small stealth recon drone. I have to  say it's useless in game though, one is enough. It probably was programmed just to make it more realistic.